# Making custom WooCommerce loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using already designed theme for wordpress, and now instead of regular blog posts I would like to display WooCommerce products (which are custom post types I persume).

This is the current query with display loop:

```
<?php 
                $args = array(
                    //'posts_per_page' => '2',
                    'paged' => get_query_var('paged')
                );
                $homepage_query = new WP_Query($args);
            ?>
            <?php //query_posts('posts_per_page=4&paged='.get_query_var('paged')); ?>
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>  
                <?php while ( $homepage_query->have_posts() ) : $homepage_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php if($style == 'blog_style') { ?>
                    <div id="blog-style" class="post-box">
                        <?php get_template_part('content', 'blog'); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                    <div class="post-box grid_4 <?php aero_post_box_class(); ?>">
                        <?php get_template_part('content', ''); ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php } ?>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Is there a way to add options to `$args` so the loop displays WooCommerce products? I'm also using pagination with this loop, which is required on this project, so that's why it's important to use this loop.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You should be able to access products through the loop, setting the `post_type` arg to `product`:

```
<?php

// Setup your custom query
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', ... );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
    </a>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); // Remember to reset ?>
```

Comment: Yes it's looping now, great!

Comment: If you want to get price, etc. you may want to do: `$product = get_product($loop->post);` and then use it just like `WC_Product` is used: `echo $product->get_price_html();` etc.

Comment: get_product() is depricated now, Use $product = new WC_Product($loop->post->ID);

Comment: Shouldn't use WP_Query for a WC loop should use WC_product_Query

Answer (score 20):

This is the proper way to re-create and customize the WooCommerce product loop:

```php
  if(!function_exists('wc_get_products')) {
    return;
  }

  $paged                   = (get_query_var('paged')) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1; // if your custom loop is on a static front page then check for the query var 'page' instead of 'paged', see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters
  $ordering                = WC()->query->get_catalog_ordering_args();
  $ordering['orderby']     = array_shift(explode(' ', $ordering['orderby']));
  $ordering['orderby']     = stristr($ordering['orderby'], 'price') ? 'meta_value_num' : $ordering['orderby'];
  $products_per_page       = apply_filters('loop_shop_per_page', wc_get_default_products_per_row() * wc_get_default_product_rows_per_page());

  $products_ids            = wc_get_products(array(
    'status'               => 'publish',
    'limit'                => $products_per_page,
    'page'                 => $paged,
    'paginate'             => true,
    'return'               => 'ids',
    'orderby'              => $ordering['orderby'],
    'order'                => $ordering['order'],
  ));

  wc_set_loop_prop('current_page', $paged);
  wc_set_loop_prop('is_paginated', wc_string_to_bool(true));
  wc_set_loop_prop('page_template', get_page_template_slug());
  wc_set_loop_prop('per_page', $products_per_page);
  wc_set_loop_prop('total', $products_ids->total);
  wc_set_loop_prop('total_pages', $products_ids->max_num_pages);

  if($products_ids) {
    do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop');
    woocommerce_product_loop_start();
      foreach($products_ids->products as $featured_product) {
        $post_object = get_post($featured_product);
        setup_postdata($GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object);
        wc_get_template_part('content', 'product');
      }
      wp_reset_postdata();
    woocommerce_product_loop_end();
    do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop');
  } else {
    do_action('woocommerce_no_products_found');
  }
```

Using the code above, you would customize the `wc_get_products()` arguments to get the IDs of the products you want (if you have specific criteria). Once that code is in place, all the features of a native WooCommerce loop will be available to you—pagination, ordering, etc. [This method is superior to `WP_Query` and `get_posts()` because those two methods can break](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query).

I've written a more detailed blog post about custom WooCommerce loops here: https://cfxdesign.com/create-a-custom-woocommerce-product-loop-the-right-way/

Comment: what if the loop is for `infinite scrolling` and not for `pagination`? There will be duplicate products to display.

Comment: If you understand what's going on here then it shouldn't be a stretch to adapt this to infinite scrolling. However, just because you *can* do something, doesn't mean you should!

Comment: If `wc_get_products()` is called with `'return' => 'ids'` the loop should start as `foreach($products_ids as $featured_product) {` instead of `foreach($products_ids->products as $featured_product) {`.

Answer (score -4):

You can Also get Category using thi code

```
       $terms = get_terms('product_cat');

       foreach ($terms as $term) {
         $term_link =  get_term_link( $term, 'product_cat' );
         echo '<li><a href="' . $term_link . '">' . $term->name . '</a></li>';
       }
```

If You want only  parent category then

```
wp_list_categories('taxonomy=product_cat&orderby=order&title_li=&depth=1');
```